# R: Average variables over specific time periods

Tags: r

I'm trying to average several time period of a particular variable column in a unit-time dataframe into a new datafame that is just unit and average of each time periods. I'm not quite sure how to do this, can anyone help?

Base data:

```
A <- structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "USA", class = "factor"), 
year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005), var1 = c(2, 
5, 4, 6, 7, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Desired output

```
B <- structure(list(country1 = structure(1L, .Label = "USA", class = "factor"), 
var1.2000.2002 = 3.667, var1.2003.2005 = 7), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not helpful because we can't copy/paste the data into R for testing. How are you deciding how to make groups for your Year variable?

Comment: `aggregate(var1~country, A, mean)`

Comment: Hi, what if I want to average them with different time periods? Like average var1 based on specific country and time period (e.g. 2000-2002) and another time period (2003-2005)?